# QuickTime Player Assistive Touch Indicator Disappearing

Tags: quicktime

I'm trying to play an iPhone game on my computer by using QuickTime Player. I have a bluetooth mouse connected to my iPhone and use the assistive touch feature. On most apps, the pointer is visible on both my phone's screen and QuickTime Player, however when I open the game I am trying to play, the pointer disappears only on QuickTime while the pointer is still visible on my phone's screen. Is this an option I am able to change, so that the pointer is always visible on both QuickTime and the Phone?

Edit: I realized that it goes away when you're phone goes into full screen horizontal mode. For example, if you were watch a video and turned your phone sideways, it also disappears. I would like to disable this function if possible.